# Code for Like Box in html 4.01 transitional

Tags: html, facebook-likebox

I am trying to add a Like Box to our homepage and have used the iFrame code but it isn't working. Our homepage is html 4.01 transitional. The code Facebook gave us is:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsome.page&amp;width=172&amp;height=590&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true&amp;appId=123456789012345" 
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" 
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:172px; height:590px;" ></iframe>
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

In the string `likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsome.page&amp;` replace `some.page` with your page url (e.g. whatever comes after facebook.com/)

Comment: Hello Ennui,Thank you for your answer! However, this is what I pasted in:<iframe
src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPiecemakers-Country-Store%2F139337029441510&amp;width=172&amp;height=375&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true&amp;appId=123456789012345"
allowtransparency="true"
style="border: medium none ; overflow: hidden; width: 172px; height: 375px;"
frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>     and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried:   <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2‌​Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.piecemakers.com%2&amp;width=172&amp;height=375‌​&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;h‌​eader=true&amp;appId=123456789012345" allowtransparency="true" style="border: medium none ; overflow: hidden; width: 172px; height: 375px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>